# How to create a vertical sliding images in Swipable cards like badoo and bumble

Tags: android, swipe, tinder

How to create a vertical sliding images in the swipable cards like badoo and bumble in android

Can u Please help me

Thanks in Advance

Comment: **Welcome to Stack Overflow**, StackOverflow is neither a forum, tutorial site nor web search replacement. We can [**help with certain problems**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but it's your job to [**put some efforts**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) in the first place, including elementary [**(re)search**](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=KlC2WdDPCKzT8gfFz72QDw). Read [**how to ask perfect question**](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

https://github.com/Diolor/Swipecards

with example:

[image]

I hope it can help your problem!

Comment: Thank you but i need vertical image sliding with in the swipe card
Can u please suggest

Comment: @Anil Did you get any success for achieving bumble card like swipe gesture ?